# Music app for large library over samba share

Tags: 12.04, samba, music-player

I am currently using Smb4k to auto-mount my Samba share (a 2TB hard drive plugged into my router USB port). The music collection is only a few hundred GBs. I've tried adding my music collection to a number of different apps, so far with no luck.

I have tried:

1) Clementine
2) Exaile
3) Spotify

The issues with each are:

1) File loading never completes. Even after waiting days. It approaches 90% and then the percentage complete begins dropping. I have no idea why this is happening

2) Exaile is just buggy. The files seem to eventually load (well, I have only tried the albums starting with "A") but even with this small collection loaded I have interrupted music playback and frequent fading out of the app GUI (while it 'thinks')

3) Spotify just doesn't seem to scan the mounted share at all. I can't get anywhere, which is a shame.. as it's a great way to catalog your collection with the additional online resource in one searchable library.

Playback through Audacious works fine when I drop in a folder from the mounted share. The playback seems relatively flawless and snappy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like Tomahawk can handle my library. Great. Now I only wish I could use Clementine or Spotify. bummer.

Comment: Better yet, deadbeef.. wow.. working flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/) (I did not test it, but looks like it has SMB support since version 2.2), [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/), aTunes, or [other alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/amarok/?platform=linux)?

Comment: If you have a really large database library you should use Amarok + mysql: http://digitizor.com/2010/05/27/how-to-use-mysql-database-in-amarok/

Comment: Some official info: http://community.kde.org/Amarok/Community/MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Rhythmbox handles big music libraries quite happily. I answered a similar question regarding Rhythmbox with Samba shares:

[Rhythmbox's not playing music from network share](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127272/rhythmboxs-not-playing-music-from-network-share)

You'll probably have to modify this method slightly to account for your HDD being plugged directly into your router - I'm not sure how your router would mount the drive or share it on the network, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What I'm used in the past for local network music server is tangerine. It's an DAAP (Digital Audio Access Protocol) server similar to what iTunes uses.

http://linuxpoison.blogspot.fr/2012/05/installconfigure-music-server-using.html

I accessed the server easily with Rhythmbox's built in DAAP client (you need to have the plugin enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I right-click a music file or a complete folder hierarchy and then choose to open with e.g. Audacious it works! I still cannot drag'n'drop or double click the files. But I'm happy with this solution.